# How do I make a Droplet to open a webpage?

Tags: macos, ssh, proxy, virtual-machine, atg-droplet

I have a droplet from the website Digitalocean.com and would like to SSH into the servers to keep a few webpages open.

How would I SSH into that? The webpages use JSON data that is sent a mysql server, so having the webpages open is the only way the data is recorded.

Comment: You'd need a real browser running on your server to do that. All command line tools I know can just make single requests; none of them is capable of keeping a site "open" and periodically running Ajax requests and such

Comment: OK, can a droplet have a real browser running or is it not capable of that?

Comment: I do not know, however some Googling (`digital ocean droplet run browser`)  suggests it is possible: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/remote-web-browsing-on-droplet